# Poner pantalla a fullscreen y que se mantenga aunque se pulse en otro sitio de la página

Tags: javascript, html, web

Buenos días.

Tengo un botón que al pulsarlo se pone el navegador en pantalla completa, y otro botón que al pulsarlo se quita la pantalla completa.

Hasta aquí todo me funciona ok. El problema que tengo es que cuando pongo en pantalla completa, si pulso en otro sitio de la misma web (otra opción del menú, etc) se quita automáticamente la pantalla completa.

El código es el siguiente:

```
function pasarPantallaCompleta(element){
    // Encuentra el método correcto, llama al elemento correcto
    if(element.requestFullScreen) {
        element.requestFullScreen();
    } else if(element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        element.mozRequestFullScreen();
           } else if(element.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
                    element.webkitRequestFullScreen();
                }
                // Lanza en pantalla completa en navegadores que lo soporten
                launchFullScreen(document.documentElement); // la página entera
            }
```

Esta es la función encargada de ponerlo en pantalla completa. Lo que quiero es que se mantenga en pantalla completa hasta que se llame a la otra función de quitar pantalla completa.

He probado a llamar a la función todo el tiempo pero no funciona.

¿Alguna idea?

Muchísimas gracias.

Este es el código que quita la pantalla completa:

```
function quitarPantallaCompleta() {
    if(document.cancelFullScreen) {
        document.cancelFullScreen();
    } else if(document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
            document.mozCancelFullScreen();
        } else if(document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {
                    document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
                }
            }
```

Lo tengo hecho con dos enlaces para poder poner un dibujo. Por tanto lo pongo así. Ejemplo completo:

```
<a href="javascript: pasarPantallaCompleta(document.documentElement)"></a>
<a href="javascript: quitarPantallaCompleta()"></a>
```

Comment: Dónde llamas a estas 2 funciones? Únicamente en cada uno de los botones?

Comment: Sí. Al pulsar un botón, llamo a "pasarPantallaCompleta". Al pulsar el otro botón llamo a "quitarPantallaCompleta"

Comment: ¿Puedes crear un [mcve] para que podamos reproducir el problema?

Comment: Solo falta poner en un botón onclick="pasarPantallaCompleta(document.documentElement)" y en otro botón onclick="quitarPantallaCompleta()".